# Save the Promise.all into two variables

Tags: javascript

I have this code and I want save the result of Promise.all into two variables.
The problem is that I gets undefined when (this.data = data)

```
    const {data,recents} : any = await Promise.all([
      this.$store.dispatch('algo', input),
      this.$store.dispatch('algo', input)
    ])
    this.data = data
    this.recents = recents
```

Comment: I would assume that `Promise.all` resolves an array. So using object destructuring won't work. Try array destructuring instead?

Comment: What do you mean with "store the result"? `Promise.all` does not yield a result beyond [a single Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that resolves only after all promises in the array of "to wait for" promises have resolved.

Answer (score 5):

[`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns a promise that will fulfill with an *array* of the individual promises' results. You cannot destructure arbitarily named object properties from there - use array destructuring instead!

```
const [data, recents] = await Promise.all([
//    ^             ^
    this.$store.dispatch('algo', input),
    this.$store.dispatch('algo', input)
])
this.data = data
this.recents = recents
```

or shorter without the temporary variables:

```
;[this.data, this.recents] = await Promise.all([
    this.$store.dispatch('algo', input),
    this.$store.dispatch('algo', input)
])
```

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that Promise.all resolves an array. So using object destructuring won't work.

Try array destructuring instead:

```js
(async() => {

  const [
    data,
    recents
  ] = await Promise.all([
    Promise.resolve('data'),
    Promise.resolve('recents')
  ]);

  console.log(
    data,
    recents
  );

})();
```